# Writing X11/Xorg packets to file in a remote Linux server

Tags: linux, sockets, ssh, x11, xorg

My understanding is that when I run `ssh -X coder0@roku2`, the ssh server inside `roku2` (assuming a default configuration) starts an X display on port `:10`, which corresponds to TCP port `6010`. When I run some graphical process like `xterm`, it then proxies traffic from port `6010` to port `22` on `roku2` to send back and forth graphical packets that are rendered my laptop.

I'm trying to write the X11 packets that get sent in a graphical process running on `roku2` to a file inside `roku2`. Therefore, I tried to login without the `-X` flag and start my own display inside `roku2` by simply running `Xorg :10`. However, I get told that only console users are allowed to do this operation.

Why is it possible for me to start an X display through `ssh`, but not directly? Is there any way I can start a X display directly so that I can write the packets that come to it to a file inside `roku2`?

Note 1: Solving this error through means displayed on other forums (https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/2676) is not possible since I dont have the privileges in `roku2` to alter the config files that I need to change.

Note 2: It seems that I should be able to start a new X display without having any special privileges in the first place: the invocation

```
Xorg -noreset +extension GLX +extension RANDR +extension RENDER -logfile ./10.log -config ./xorg.conf :10
```

is used on https://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Xdummy to start a display without any need to be sudo or a console user. This by the way, also fails for me.

Comment: You are not starting an X server through ssh, you are telling ssh to work as an X11 proxy. A real X server needs graphic hardware to display stuff on, this is why you cannot start one. You should be able to run Xvfb instead.

Comment: In Xorg, the notions between server and client are reversed. You start X displays / X clients in the remote host (roku2), the X server is actually on my laptop. So I can start my X server anytime, the ssh client just manages X clients inside roku2. I can start X displays inside roku2 with ssh but not directly, and I am wondering why that is.

Comment: @n.m. confirmation of terminology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#/media/File:X_client_server_example.svg

Comment: The picture doesn't seem to agree with your terminology, which looks very non-standard to me. An X11 server is a piece of software that processes graphic requests and controls graphic hardware. Xorg is an X11 server. An X11 client is a piece of software that issues graphic requests to be processed by an X11 server. Your browser is an X11 client.

Comment: @n.m from that Wikipedia article: "This client–server terminology – the user's terminal being the server and the applications being the clients – often confuses new X users, because the terms appear reversed. But X takes the perspective of the application, rather than that of the end-user: X provides display and I/O services to applications, so it is a server; applications use these services, thus they are clients." It looks non-standard because it is. I think your definitions of X11 client and server are correct, its just that the client happens to be in the remote host, not locally present.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here. You are using the term "X display". You are saying you are able "to start an X display through ssh". What does this mean exactly? What are you starting and with what exact command? Normally an "X display" is a part of an X server and can colloquially be used to just mean "X server", but what do you mean by it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131777/discussion-between-coder-and-n-m).

Comment: Well I have re-read the conversation and none of it seems to make sense. Let's return to my first comment. You are not starting a real X server in roku2,  you are telling ssh to proxy X traffic to your laptop. Any objections so far?